# Should I pass encrypted data in a JWT token?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, encryption, jwt

We are implementing JWT to allow our client side to authenticate through our separate authentication server.

The client posts the username and password to the authentication server, receives a JWT and then logs in to the main site with the JWT.

Clearly, the token includes the username and some other non-secret information.

The question is if to use JWT to pass secret information and how.
Here are a few options that might be considered:

1. Don't do it. Have the main website server call a back-end API with the authenticated username to get the information it needs.
2. Pass the information as Private claims *encrypting the values* with a symmetric encryption and sharing the key/pass-phrase between the main website and the authentication server.
3. Encrypt the entire token.

Are there any best practices here? what are the ups and downs of these options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use JWT for passing secret information.
These tokens are usually signed to protect against manipulation (not encrypted) so the data in the claims can be easily decoded and read.
If you need to pass sensitive information please look at [JSON Web Encryption(JWE)](http://hdknr.github.io/docs/identity/jwe.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should check [JSON Web Encryption](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) for this purpose